# Mouse on the Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, mouse

Conventional wisdom is that you can't use a mouse on the Xbox 360 (you can use a keyboard though). XNA Game Studio claims [not to support it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.mouse.aspx#note) for example. (has anyone tested it? I should probably ask on stackoverflow)

However, [this support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909159) claims that "Most USB mouse devices and USB keyboards" ... "are compatible with the Xbox 360".

Also, the Microsoft [Wired Desktop 600](http://www.microsoft.com/australia/hardware/mouseandkeyboard/ProductDetails.aspx?pid=039&active_tab=systemRequirements) Keyboard & Mouse page claims

> **Mouse Features**
>
> - Great for Gaming - Xbox 360 Compatibility
>     Perfect for texting and accessing playlists.

**Is this for real?** Will the mouse do anything when plugged into the 360?

Comment: Reading the line on the Wired Desktop 600. I'm wondering if the mouse line is just in the wrong place or something. I know you can use keyboards for text input and messaging, so the texting makes sense for the keyboard, but not at all for the mouse.

Comment: @Blake: yes I had the same thought. I'm just hoping I'm wrong and there is some way to use the mouse :)

Answer (score 5):

In regards to direct mouse input: No. Mouse input is not supported. Other than plugging it in and trying, I would say it does nothing and can think of nowhere on the interface that it would do anything.

I could find nothing on Xbox Support's site, but [did get a response from their Twitter support @xboxsupport](https://twitter.com/#!/XboxSupport/status/67938327474601984)

> Mouse input is not supported for the Xbox 360

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Yes. However, I have not heard of direct mouse input without some sort of interface between the mouse. Two products I've heard of that accomplish this:

- [XIM3](http://xim3.com/) seems to be the latest one released. There is [some](http://kotaku.com/#!5715140/use-a-mouse--keyboard-on-your-xbox-360) [news](http://www.engadget.com/2011/02/05/xim3-xbox-360-keyboard-mouse-etc-adapter-goes-on-sale-imme/) although it seems it's out of stock. The Amazon reviews on it seem fishy.
- A company called XCM makes a line of accessories called [XFPS](http://www.xcm.cc/360.htm).

I have no experience with either of the above.

Comment: Those hardware adapters translate mouse motion into (virtual) thumbstick movement. I'm talking about plugging a mouse directly into the 360's USB port.

Answer (score 1):

Ive tried various wireless and wired mouse sets and nothing happens... Havent tried keyboards though. 'Benny Fish' is correct, the "smart Glass' xbox360 smartphone app is excellent, your phone becomes a keyboard AND a mouse....well worth a look in

Answer (score -2):

I have the wireless keyboard and mouse set. They are the wireless keyboard and mouse 2000v. The keyboard has great compatibility, but the mouse does nothing. There are 2 options for a mouse. First, is the xbox smartglass app for your phone, and the other being just a regular xbox controller. I only use my keyboard for internet explorer, and it makes no sense that the mouse wouldn't work. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm, I read twice and still not sure what are you trying to say. Could you reformat your answer ?